# How to set a different directory in Pandoc

Tags: output, pandoc

Someone suggested me to convert .tex files into Word documents via Pandoc.
However, I don't understand how to set a different directory for Pandoc to search the .tex file… And I cannot find the Pandoc main directory (mac os x lion), too.

What I am trying is: pandoc dir=/Users/albertofara/GoogleDrive/lavori/05actinomycosis/latex -s actinomycosis.tex -o actynomicosis.rtf

but I get this error: pandoc: dir=/Users/albertofara/GoogleDrive/lavori/05actinomycosis/latex/actinomycosis.tex: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open the terminal and use `cd` to change to the directory your files are in. Enter this at the  prompt:

```
cd /Users/albertofara/GoogleDrive/lavori/05actinomycosis/latex
```

Then run pandoc from that directory:

```
pandoc -s actinomycosis.tex -o actynomicosis.rtf
```